# Build fails - "Framework not found FBSDKCoreKit" after de-installing FB Pod

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I've just removed the Facebook pod from my project (I'm no longer supporting sign-in with Facebook) and now the build is failing with the following message:

ld: framework not found FBSDKCoreKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've taken the following actions so far:

- Removed the Facebook pod from the podfile and done a $ pod install to remove the SDK
- Removed the Facebook entries from my plist file
- Ensured there are no files importing any of the Facebook SDKs

However, there's obviously still a reference to the FBSDKCoreKit in my project somewhere, but for the life of me I can't find it.

Can anyone suggest where it might be?

Comment: Try searching for this reference in the following places: General -> "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content", Build phases -> "Link Binary with Libraries" or "Embed Frameworks".  Another thing I would try is to remove all pods (use pod init to create a blank podfile and run pod install) and then restoring them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Arek. Couldn't find the reference anywhere so have ended up creating a new project, reinstalling the other pods and copying across the swift files. All is now ok. Thanks, Facebook!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build Settings - Other Linker Flags and remove

```
-framework
"FBSDKCoreKit"
```